# SQL for table 1 date between 2 columns in table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

What is the best way to code the SQL to get the records from table 1 where the date in table 1 is between 2 column dates in table 2?

Something like

```
SELECT INVOICE.* from INVOICE, CYCLE
Where
INVOICE.inv_date BETWEEN cycle.start_date and cycle.end_date
```

The Cycle table only has one row, and changes nightly.

The INVOICE table has 6 million invoices going back many years.

I'm looking for something that (a) works well, and (b) is efficient.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `Cycle` table has only one row

you can get the start date and end date in variables and do the `select` instead of joining with `cycle` table

```
declare @start_date datetime
declare @end_date datetime

select @start_date = start_date, @end_date = end_date FROM Cycle

-- select required columns instead of all

SELECT invoice.inv_date .. 
FROM INVOICE 
WHERE INOVICE.inv_date between @start_date and @end_date
```

Comment: Ahh, I forgot to mention one detail. This is SQL for an ETL application, so it's straight SQL only. No declares, no variables, no multiple select statements. The "Source" SQL as it were. So given that, what is the best way in a single SQL statement to do this?